# CSS focus styling not working but hover is

Tags: css, reactjs, focus

I am trying to highlight a button when the user tabs to it. I can get it to highlight on hover but on focus doesn't work.

This is my CSS:

```
#pagingBtn :focus, #pagingBtn :hover {
 background: red; 
}
```

(Not actually having it as red it's just easier to see when testing as it's glaringly obvious)

This is my button:

```
<CommandButton
 id="pagingBtn"
 disabled={fetching ? fetching : (count - (fileDisplayAmmount * page) <= fileDisplayAmmount)}
 data-automation-id='FileForward'
 iconProps={{ iconName: 'ChromeBackMirrored' }}
 onClick={() => pageFiles(query, fileDisplayAmmount, page + 1, orderBy, order)}>
Next
</CommandButton>
```

Anyone any ideas how to fix this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: It worked! Thank you! Hate it when something silly like that affects it so much

Comment: Voting to Close as this question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers.